# Display Alert in Fragment inside a ViewPager not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm using an awesome library : [Alerter](https://github.com/Tapadoo/Alerter). I have 3 fragments inside a ViewPager. When I display a fragment, I want to display an Alert with this library. However, the alert is not showing up the first time. When I click on a button to display a new one, the first one shuws and juste after the second one. Just like the alert was delayed until a new one is requested.

Here is the ocde I use  for the Main Fragment :

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());

        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                FragmentLifecycle fragmentToShow = (FragmentLifecycle) adapter.getItem(position);
                fragmentToShow.onResumeFragment();
            }
        });

        final int pageMargin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 4, getResources()
                .getDisplayMetrics());
        pager.setPageMargin(pageMargin);

        tabs.setViewPager(pager);
    }

    private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private final String[] TITLES = {"Cube", "Osselet", "Watch"};

        private MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return TITLES[position];
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return TITLES.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // Return Map Fragment
            if (position == 0) {
                return new RecordCubeFragment();
            }
            //Return Toilet List Fragment
            else if (position == 1) {
                return new RecordOsseletFragment();
            }
            else if (position == 2) {
                return new RecordWatchFragment();
            }
            else {
                return new RecordCubeFragment();
            }
        }
```

And there is the code of a child fragment in the ViewPager :

```
@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "call oncreateview");
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_record_cube, container, false);

        lectureButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.lectureButton);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "call onview created");
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        lectureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    Alerter.create(getActivity())
                            .setTitle("Warning !")
                            .setText("second alert.")
                            .setIcon(R.drawable.alert_icon)
                            .setBackgroundColorInt(Color.RED)
                            .setDuration(2000)
                            .show();
            }
        });
        Alerter.create(getActivity())
                            .setTitle("Warning !")
                            .setText("first alert.")
                            .setIcon(R.drawable.alert_icon)
                            .setBackgroundColorInt(Color.RED)
                            .setDuration(2000)
                            .show();
    }
```

Thx for the help, I know that lifeCycle of fragments is different in ViewPager, this is why I implemented an OnPageChangeListener but I cannot get rid of this problem.

Comment: One thing you can do when you create fragment, pass your mainactivity.this to constructor in fragment. Instead of using getActivity, use mainactivity in alerter

Comment: How can I do that ?